# aggregation issue mssql with join and parent-child level

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate, parent-child

The source table examples

```
Table1
id      id_parent   product_id    
===     =========   ========    
154     104389        1043891       
155     104389        1995137331
```

then I have two other inventory tables as below:

```
(table2)
product_id   location_id       on_hand     transit
1043891          2           12      1
1043891          5           33      0
1043891          6           7       0
1043891          4           3       0
1995137331       2           8       5
1995137331       8           50      9
1995137331       5           95      0
1995137331       11          22      5
1995137331       13          93      1

(table3)
product_id   location_id    on_hand      transit
1043891           1         25       1
1995137331        1         29       0
```

I have this following query:

```
; with 
O as (select Product_Id, SUM(OnHand) AS AllStore from Table2 group by Product_Id),
S as (select Product_Id, SUM(OnHand) as WH from Table3 group by Product_Id)

SELECT
   L1.id_parent as parent
  ,L1.product_id as child
  , O.AllStore
  , S.WH
FROM Table1 L0 JOIN Table1 L1 ON L0.id_parent = L1.id_parent 

LEFT OUTER JOIN S on S.Product_ID = L0.Product_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN O on O.Product_ID = L0.Product_ID
group by L1.id_parent, L1.product_id, S.WH, O.AllStore
```

It's somewhat working but duplicating the records. current result:

```
parent  child       AllStore    WH
1043892 1043891     104         102
1043892 1043891     242         123
1043892 1995137331  104         102
1043892 1995137331  242         123
```

Expected result:

```
parent  child       AllStore    WH
1043892 1043891     104         102
1043892 1995137331  242         123
```

Can someone please look at it and see what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you use `DISTINCT`??

Comment: Without information on how the data is structured and what the expected result is. This is really just guessing for all of us.

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't change the result set.

Comment: It's not possible for your query to produce actual duplicates.   Maybe you have some values with whitespace that causes them to look like duplicates.   Can you script sample tables with data that reproduces the issue?   I'm guessing not.

Comment: Please look at my original post. I've added table examples. sqlfiddle isn't working. is there an alternative? What I'm trying to do is, list all child id for each parent and list their available quantities. Getting quantities from 2 tables and summing them up into 2 groups, for location 1 and all other locations.

Comment: Given the sample data you added, what duplicates are you seeing in your results?

Comment: Tab Alleman, please see my edits, I've added current and expected result. Thanks. http://pastebin.com/d4spCHUQ

Comment: This portion confuses me as these items aren't in your table definition `FROM Table3 L0 JOIN Table3 L1 ON L0.id_parent = L1.id_parent`

Comment: I think the issue is with parent-child join. even when I supply a single child_id, it brings in all the child with it.

Comment: Zane, sorry about that. I fixed the table name references above. It should be table1 that has parent-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues comes due to your join of Table1 onto itself with the condition of

```
L0.id_parent = L1.id_parent
```

This join effectively Takes Table 1 with 2 rows of 104389 and joins on itself with the 2 rows. This join condition will produce 4 rows.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM 
    @Table1 L0
    INNER JOIN @Table1 L1 ON
        L0.id_parent = L1.id_parent

id          id_parent   product_id  id          id_parent   product_id
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
154         104389      1043891     154         104389      1043891
154         104389      1043891     155         104389      1995137331
155         104389      1995137331  154         104389      1043891
155         104389      1995137331  155         104389      1995137331
```

From the examples you have given, this join is completely unnecessary as the data you need is already in L0

The group by statement is also unnecessary as you are not running any aggregates. the end result of leaving it in is the same as putting a DISTINCT on the overall query.

Therefore: to produce the described "Expected Results"
the query can be modified to the below

```
; with 
O as (select Product_Id, SUM(on_hand) AS AllStore from @Table2 group by Product_Id),
S as (select Product_Id, SUM(on_hand) as WH from @Table3 group by Product_Id)

SELECT
   L0.id_parent as parent
  ,L0.product_id as child
  ,O.AllStore
  ,S.WH
FROM
    @Table1 L0

    LEFT OUTER JOIN S ON
        S.Product_ID = L0.Product_Id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN O ON
        O.Product_ID = L0.Product_ID
```

Note: If the L0 and L1 join is a typo, and there is a 4th table in play but still producing duplicates, you can extract the L0 and L1 join into a sub query and DISTINCT it.

Comment: Lu, Thanks a lot for your response with the solution. It worked as I explained my problem. My goal for this report is to read a list of productID's from a table, bring in all it's siblings(including itself) from Table1, and their count from table2 and table3. Just not sure what's the best way to engineer this.

Comment: @Eclipse Unfortunately without more information, am unable to help further. I can only say that in my experience, it's sometimes easier to maintain/debug if you create a temp table, put all filtered base data with id's in it, then join on the other tables for the aggregates

Comment: Lu,
So I have a list of products (list of id's). They could either be a child or parent product(not all products have parent/child hierarchy). I want to list all products that are child and is in the list I checked against. List all their siblings and stock count for them.

Comment: Eclipse, Can you elaborate on what you mean by listing siblings and stock count for them. Are you wanting all products under the parents to sum into 1 value?

If your table 1 is the mapping between child and parent, then all siblings would exist in table with the same parent id. If you are wanting the sum to be at child/sibling level, there is no need to involve or re-involve the parent id. 

If the query I suggested doesn't work on your actual data, then perhaps give a more elaborate sample data and expected results so that we can understand the scenario better.

Comment: Lu, Please see my post here http://pastebin.com/gRM5dCMm as it's too long to be written here. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Eclipse, Hopefully I'm understanding your description correctly.

Essentially the core of the problem was getting the sum of product on hand for all sibling product and itself give a list of product id's. 

If I understood you correctly, the query in your latest pastebin is almost there. Instead of left joining onto your cte within this query of yours, you should use the current query to replace @Table0 in my suggested answer above.

the result will be something along the lines of this
http://pastebin.com/7JgWSNLW

Comment: An alternative to the nested WHERE ... IN
you could use a join. 
The result is very similar to what you were originally trying to achieve in your question. http://pastebin.com/CZ8E6TJt

essentially your original logic of Table0 joining on Table0 on parent_id was on right path, but it should be a sub query and not have been part of the joins onto the 2 cte's

Comment: Thanks a lot Lu Henry for your help with this.